# Partition function for two particles such as bosons fermions

Tags: statistical-mechanics

What is the difference between partition function for two-boson system and two-fermion system?

Comment: Partition functions describe ensembles of many particles. It sounds like you're asking about two-particle systems, is that correct?

Comment: Yes exactly, two-particle systems such as two-bosons or two-fermions. What is the difference between partition function of these two systems?